# Any problems with using a period in URLs to delimiter data?

Tags: url, cross-browser

I have some easy to read URLs for finding data that belongs to a collection of record IDs that are using a comma as a delimiter.

Example:

```
http://www.example.com/find:1%2C2%2C3%2C4%2C5
```

I want to know if I change the delimiter from a comma to a period. Since periods are not a special character in a URL. That means it won't have to be encoded.

Example:

```
http://www.example.com/find:1.2.3.4.5
```

Are there any browsers (Firefox, Chrome, IE, etc) that will have a problem with that URL?

There are some related questions here on SO, but none that specific say it's a good or bad practice.

Comment: It shouldn't be a problem, as long as you won't try to use something like slash as delimiter. Then you'd need some rewrite rules, but on the client side, it's still all right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me, that looks like a resource  *with an odd query string format*.
If I understand correctly this would be equal to something like:

```
http://www.example.com/find?id=1&id=2&id=3&id=4&id=5
```

Since your filter is acting like a multi-select (IDs instead of search fields), that would be my guess at a standard equivalent.

Browsers *should* not have any issues with it, as long as the application's route mechanism handles it properly. And as long as you are not building that query-like thing with an HTML form (in which case you would need JS or some rewrites, ew!).

May I ask why not use a more standard URL and querystring? Perhaps something that includes element class (`/reports/search?name=...`), just to know *what is being queried by find*. Just curious, I knows sometimes standards don't apply.

Comment: `http://www.example.com/action/name:value/name:value/name:value` are called named parameters in CakePHP. It's an alternative to using GET parameters. I like using them cause they compact the URL cleanly don't make parameters look like a tail added to a URL. With that said, I heard they are getting rid of them in CakePHP 3.0, so might only be a phase the framework is going through.